# Display text in TextBox after press Enter key

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I want to know how to display some text in the textbox after pressing enter key using VB.net. I have some code below but my code doesn't work. It display Box 1, Box 2 and Box 3 and the same time after I press Enter key for the first time. Note that I have 3 textbox.

```
    Private Sub OnKeyDownHandler(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown, TextBox2.KeyDown, TextBox3.KeyDown
    Dim i As Short

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim CurrentControl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
        Me.SelectNextControl(CurrentControl, True, True, True, True)
        For i = 0 To 2
            txtBox(i).Text = "Box " + (i + 1).ToString
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I know it seems simple but I can't think any ways to solve it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you obviously need to remove the `For i = 0 To 2` loop since it iterates all text boxes at the same time.

There are then two ways you can do this:

### Method 1: Extract the number from the name

Since all your text boxes' names start with `TextBox` and then its number you can extract the number by removing the `TextBox` part:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim CurrentControl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
    Me.SelectNextControl(CurrentControl, True, True, True, True)

    If CurrentControl.Name.StartsWith("TextBox") Then
        CurrentControl.Text = "Box " & CurrentControl.Name.Remove("TextBox".Length)
    End If
End If
```

### Method 2: Get the number from the index of the text box in your array

Although **Method 1** is the recommended way, you can also use your `txtBox` array to get the text box's index:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim CurrentControl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
    Me.SelectNextControl(CurrentControl, True, True, True, True)

    Dim Index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(txtBox, CurrentControl)
    If Index > -1 Then
        CurrentControl.Text = "Box " & (Index + 1)
    End If
End If
```

This of course means that you would have to update your array as you add more text boxes.

Comment: @izwanismail : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!